# PHP Page load/refresh to exact position

Tags: php, refresh, href

What I'm trying to do is to pass a user to a php script via a href link, then have them passed back to exactly the same position that they were at before they clicked the link, like the page hasn't been refreshed. Does anyone know if or how this could be possible possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Using HTML you can have the following

```
<p id='open_here'><a href='script.php'> Send to script </a> </p>
```

And then you can link back to that exact position with

```
<a href="mypage.html#open_here">Send Back to page</a>
```

So essentially, instead of using a regular link as in the previuos code snippet, you could redirect back to the page using

```
//php redirect
<?php header('Location: mypage.html#open_here'); ?>

//Javascript redirect
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.location = "mypage.html#open_here";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. I had thought if doing it that way but I was just wondering if there was a smoother way of doing it. Kind of like a javascript false return but in php!

Comment: I don't believe you're going to be doing that in strict php.  If you use jQuery scrollTop without an argument to get its current vertical scroll position and then use scrollTop again with the position as an argument to move to that position in the page.  You could either run the php through ajax and on success move to that position, or you could pass the position to the script and back. That could be messy on its own though

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind adding some Javascript to make it work, here is a solution that will make it possible to redirect back to the exact same scrollbar position as when the user clicked the link.

**`index.php` (the file where the link is)**

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Do we have a #scroll in the URL hash?
        if(window.location.hash && /#scroll/.test(window.location.hash)) {
            // Scroll to the #scroll value
            window.scrollTo(0, window.location.hash.replace('#scroll=', ''));
        }

        // Get all <a> elements with data-remember-position attribute
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-remember-position]');

        if(links.length) {
            // Loop through the found links
            for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                // Listen for clicks
                links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    // Prevent normal redirection
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // Redirect manually but put the current scroll value at the end
                    window.location = this.href + '?scroll=' + window.scrollY;
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**`page.php` (the PHP script that redirects back)**

```
<?php

// Get the provided scroll position if it exists, otherwise put 0
$scrollPos = (array_key_exists('scroll', $_GET)) ? $_GET['scroll'] : 0; 

// Redirect back to index.php and provide the scroll position as a hash value
header('Location: index.php#scroll='.$scrollPos);
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: By far the best solution that can also be extended to work on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

I am just spilling ideas here, but I would use javascript to intercept user's click on the href, and .preventDefault first. Then figure out where the user is on the page. Maybe by splitting the page into sections, indentified by IDs. Your html markup would be something like

```
<div id="section-1"></div>
<div id="section-2"></div>
<div id="section-3"></div>
```

so when javascript prevents the link from executing, it would figure out in which section the user currently is. Let's say we know each section's height. Then we need to find out the scrollbar position. I haven't done that, but have a look here

```
http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/
```

Once we know the height of each section and once we can detect where the scroll bar is, we can determine in which section the user is residing. Then, we fetch the url of the href link and add a query string to it like, http://something.com/script.php?section=2 and redirect user to it with whatever data you want . Then once the script has done it's job append the query string to the redirect-uri and redirect the user back with something like http://something.com#section-2 and the user will immediatly pop to section-2

I know this isn't a very specific answer, but hopefully I've given you some leads and ideas how to accomplish this. Let me know how it works!

Answer (score 0):

I'd had to remember the scroll position for a <select>. Example below. Three
submit buttons to illustrate why there's three getElementById. To see
it work you must move the scroll bar first

```
<?php
$scrollusObscura=$_GET["imgbtn"];

$header = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>snk_db</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >

<head>
<script>
    function gety(){

        var y=document.getElementById('myUlID').scrollTop;
        document.getElementById('imgbtn1').value=y; 
        document.getElementById('imgbtn2').value=y;
        document.getElementById('imgbtn3').value=y;
    }
    function itemRelevatur(scrollum){
        document.getElementById('myUlID').scrollTo(0, scrollum);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body  onload="itemRelevatur({$scrollusObscura})" >
EOD;
$html= <<<EOD
<div >

<select size="6" id="myUlID" name="myUlName" onscroll="myTimer = setInterval(gety, 300)">
    <option>'1'</option>
    <option>'2'</option>
    <option>'3'</option>
    <option>'4'</option>
    <option>'5'</option>
    <option>'6'</option>
    <option>'7'</option>
    <option>'8'</option>
    <option>'9'</option>
    <option>'10'</option>
    <option>'11'</option>
    <option>'12'</option>
    <option>'13'</option>
    <option>'14'</option>
    <option>'15'</option>
    <option>'16'</option>
    <option>'17'</option>
    <option>'18'</option>
    <option>'19'</option>
</select>

</div>
EOD;


$html1= <<<EOD
<div><form method='GET' action'myscript.php'>
            <input type='hidden' name='imgbtn' id='imgbtn1' value=''></input>
            <input type='submit'  value='Submit' ></input>
</form>
EOD;
$html2= <<<EOD
<form method='GET' action'myscript.php'>
            <input type='hidden' name='imgbtn' id='imgbtn2' value=''></input>
            <input type='submit'  value='Submit' ></input>
</form>
EOD;
$html3= <<<EOD
<form method='GET' action'myscript.php'>
            <input type='hidden' name='imgbtn' id='imgbtn3' value=''></input>
            <input type='submit'  value='Submit' ></input>
</form></div>
EOD;

echo $header;
echo $html;
echo $html1;
echo $html2;
echo $html3."</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had major problems with cookie javascript libraries, most cookie libraries could not load fast enough before i needed to scroll in the onload event.  so I went for the modern html5 browser way of handling this. it stores the last scroll position in the client web browser itself, and then on reload of the page reads the setting from the browser back to the last scroll position.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (localStorage.getItem("my_app_name_here-quote-scroll") != null) {
        $(window).scrollTop(localStorage.getItem("my_app_name_here-quote-scroll"));
    }

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        localStorage.setItem("my_app_name_here-quote-scroll", $(window).scrollTop());
    });

  });
</script>
```