# scroll back to where I was after redirecting back to the same page

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, scroll

I have a link in A.php that redirects to B.php. In B.php, i do something, and redirect instantly back to A.php. I want it to also scroll to the initial y position.

How can I do that?

I tried this

```
<body  onUnload="document.cookie='ypos=' + window.pageYOffset" onLoad='window.scrollTo(0,$_COOKIE["ypos"])'>
```

But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555678/php-page-load-refresh-to-exact-position might help.

Comment: Won't help, because in B.php I delete the entry in the database that represents the link in A.php, so it doesn't exist when I redirect back.

Comment: well, for starters, your php code block is missing <?php echo...?>

Comment: lol, thanks. That's it. It still doesn't do what I want, but now I can debug.